# rails nested_forms error and logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'am trying to add some fields to my nested form. I've included the gem `nested_forms` (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).

For my prebuilt maps, it works fine, but i can't add new fields.

My controller:

```
def new
  @people = Person.all
  @vehicles = Vehicle.all
  @roles = Role.all
  @pratice_people = []
  @people.each do |a|
    if a.at1 == true
      @pratice_people << a
    end
  end
  @practice = Practice.new
  @pratice_people.count.times { @practice.uebung_maps.build }
  render action: "new"
end
```

and my form:

```
 <% @runs = 0 %>
 <%= f.fields_for :uebung_maps do |map| %>
   <tr>
     <%= map.hidden_field :role_id, :id => "role_id_#{@runs}"  %>
     <%= map.hidden_field :vehicle_id, :id => "vehicle_id_#{@runs}"  %>
     <%= map.hidden_field :person_id , :value => @pratice_people[@runs].id %><br/>
     <td><%= @pratice_people[@runs].name %></td>
     <td><%= map.select :role_id,  options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, :id, :name), :include_blank => true %></td>
     <td><%= map.select :vehicle_id,  options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicles, :id, :name), :include_blank => true %></td>
     <td><%= map.text_field :time %></td>
   </tr>
   <% @runs += 1 %>
 <% end %>

<%= f.link_to_add "+" , :uebung_maps %>
```

If i try to access the page, i get following error report

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Do I have to (or how to) create a logic to rerun `Practice.uebung_maps.build?`, because I thought this is done within the `nested_forms` gem....

Comment: `@pratice_people[@runs]` is `nil`

Comment: okay i've now change the form, asking if @pratice_people[@runs].nil? and the form is working now, but if i click on the link nothing is happening... do i have to add another logic here?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the models are created correctly.

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :uebung_maps
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :uebung_maps
end

class UebungMap < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Second, make sure the `form_for` is nested correctly

```
<%= nested_form_for @practice do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :uebung_maps do |uebung_maps_form| %>
    <%= uebung_maps_form.text_field :time %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "+", :uebung_maps %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thats quite what i have! Do i need to write my own ajax method to build add a new one?

Comment: Because if i clock on it, nothing is happening. There are no errors in firbug console or anything else...